# access value from one template to other in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-include

How to use model value from one template1 to template2 ?

Here is my code :-
index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example84-production</title>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="includeExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
     <div ng-include="'template1.html'"></div>
    <div ng-include="'template2.html'"></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

template1.html

```
Content of template1.html
<br/>
<input ng-model="x"/>
```

template2.html

```
Content of template2.html
<br/>
x={{x}}
```

Plukr-
http://plnkr.co/edit/HF1KxLzGbmP4S7gVc5fQ?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the "controller as" syntax :

```
<body ng-app="includeExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController as ex">
     <div ng-include="'template1.html'"></div>
    <div ng-include="'template2.html'"></div>

</div>
```

and inside your templates :

```
x={{ex.x}}


<input ng-model="ex.x"/>
```

plunkr :

http://plnkr.co/edit/FVkSj2vs8WDAt1eifBpF?p=preview